# Using Transcrypt with Leaflet Maps

Tags: transcrypt

I love Python, and have never much cared for JavaScript.  So I was pretty excited to learn about Transcrypt.  I recently started a web-based project that uses Django for the back-end and a Leaflet map (specifically Esri Leaflet) that plays a central role in the front-end.  I'm trying to figure out if Transcrypt is a good fit for my project.  However, the documentation and examples on Transcrypt's website are either too simple or delve into more advanced topics too quickly.  As a result, I'm having a hard time deciding whether Transcrypt will add anything positive to my project or will simply bring more complexity and bugs.  I'd rather not spend several hours trying to get Transcrypt working (time that could be productively spent simply writing JavaScript) only to find out Transcrypt isn't a good fit for my website.  So I have a few questions.

I know Transcrypt is designed to work with any JavaScript library.  Will it also work with map-based GIS libraries?

For example, if I can successfully encapsulate the whole of Esri Leaflet (but maybe I won't be able to?), Transcrypt would allow me to write the following in Python?

```
  var map = L.map('map').setView([40.91, -96.63], 4);

  L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
  }).addTo(map);

  var arcgisOnline = L.esri.Geocoding.arcgisOnlineProvider();

  L.esri.Geocoding.geosearch({
    providers: [
      arcgisOnline,
      L.esri.Geocoding.mapServiceProvider({
        label: 'States and Counties',
        url: 'https://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/Census/MapServer',
        layers: [2, 3],
        searchFields: ['NAME', 'STATE_NAME']
      })
    ]
  }).addTo(map);
```

By the way, that code was taken from [here](https://esri.github.io/esri-leaflet/examples/search-map-service.html).

I didn't quite understand the explanations about integrating with JavaScript libraries found [here](https://www.transcrypt.org/docs/html/integration_javascript.html#three-ways-of-integration-with-javascript-libraries), specifically where it says:

> Another way is to encapsulate the JavaScript library as a whole in a Transcrypt module. In the distribution this is done for the fabric module, that encapsulates fabric.js and is imported in the Pong example. In this way the global namespace stays clean.

So I can't really tell if Transcrypt could handle all the GIS and map stuff.

The Leaflet map will be the main user interface for my site. So knowing that Transcrypt could encapsulate it is kind of important.  There will also be a lot of event listeners connected to the map, and data going back and forth between the front and back-ends. I'm probably going to be using jQuery's Ajax for a lot of that.  I saw a few simple jQuery examples on the Transcrypt website, but am not sure if Transcrypt is really up to the job yet.

I've noticed that the only person answering the Transcrypt questions is its creator, Jacques de Hooge.  I guess my questions are really directed at him.  Any advice you can offer me is much appreciated, Jacques!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to encapsulate the Leaflet library. You can use it just as is in Transcrypt.

Here an example. In a new folder create the HTML file mymap.html`:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="leaflet.css"/>
        <script src="leaflet.js"></script>        
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="the-map" style="width: 1000px; height: 800px;"></div>
        <script type="module">import * as main from './__target__/mymap.js';</script>
    </body>
</html>
```

And create the Transcrypt file `mymap.py`:

```
def main(map_id):

    watercolorTiles = {'linkTpl': 'http://c.tile.stamen.com/watercolor/{z}/{x}/{y}.jpg',
                     'attribution': '&copy; Stamen Maps'}
    australiaView = {'center': [-27.30,133.62],
                     'zoomSnap': 0.1,
                      'zoom': 4.5}

    # Build the map
    map = L.map(map_id, australiaView)
    
    L.tileLayer(watercolorTiles['linkTpl'], {
        'attribution': watercolorTiles['attribution'],
    }).addTo(map);

    
main('the-map')
```

Note that teh Transcrypt code uses the global Lefa;et object `L`  just as is. This factory object is already instantiated in `leaflet.js` and you can use it to build your map.

To view the map you need to do:

1. [Download the Leaflet library](https://leafletjs.com/download.html) and copy `leaflet.css` and `leaflet.js` into your folder.
2. On the Terminal command line (after cd'ing into your folder) transpile the `.py` file :

   ```
    $ transcrypt mymap.py
   ```
3. Fire up a webserver serving your folder, e.g. with:

   ```
   $ python3 -m http.server
   ```

Now go in your browser to http://localhost:8000/mymap.html and look at a beautiful (in this case watercolour) map of Australia.

Your *geosearch* code snippet could be written in a similarly fashion with Transcrypt - just make sure to write dictionary keys as Python strings (so instead of `attribution` write `'attribution'`)!